# What is a good way to make "custom" hyperlinks automatically clickable?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I have an asp.net mvc web page where I query data from a database and show info in a table and sometimes there are links in the content and i want to make them clickable but the interesting part is that some of these links are our custom internal links that don't have a "http" prefix.  So, for example, if I have link that looks like this:

```
home://ticket/162-4737
```

so the content of the table cell might be:

```
   We are dependent on this ticket: home://ticket/162-4737 to 
   complete the work
```

how can I automatically make that clickable on a web page.  Should I do some regex find and replace on the server side and replace the link above with something like this

```
<a href='home://ticket/162-4737'/>home://ticket/162-4737</a>
```

or is there some other recommended way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Regex is the way to go for something like this. If your content is just plain text, use a regex. If it's markdown or something else, things get a little more hairy.

Comment: I would go with regex for this. Do you have that covered, or do you need help with that?

Comment: Depends on how "good" you want. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you requested a suggestion for a regex. I would suggest something like this:

Search: `home://\S+`

Replace: `<a href='$_' />$_</a>`

- `home://` matches literal characters
- `\S+` matches any characters that are not a whitespace character (space, tab, new lines...)
- In the replacement, `$_` is ASP.NET syntax to insert the whole match.

In C# code (per your request in the comments):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"home://\S+", "<a href='$_' />$_</a>");
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  can you clarify a bit more how you can use the $_ to do the find replace in C# code.  i was just going to using string.replace but just realized i need to make it dynamic

Comment: Yes! Added that at the bottom of the answer. :) Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hey there Leora, following up on this, did the answer solve it for you, or is the question still there?

Comment: it works most of the time but i found a case where it doesn't - the original text is "Ticket-11- Error (home://ticket/162-6770)" and your answer seems to include the whole text (starting from Ticket instead of just the home url

Comment: @leora It's all a matter of knowing what can be a delimiter for the end of your url. If you say that `)` can for sure never happen in a url, then instead of using `\S+`, we use `[^)\s]+`, and the regex becomes `home://[^)\s]+` Just replace that in the C# code and let me know if it does what you want. :) Also, if there are other forbidden characters, add them to the negative character class `[^)\s]+` Yesterday's approach was a quick approach given the shape of the input you showed us, but it can be refined. Will be offline for the night, hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hey there, following up on this, is it clear now or is the question still there?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but this still doesn't seem to work . . again, to clarify, the string that is causing the issue is:  "Ticket-11- Error (home://ticket/162-6770)"  in this case the full string (starting from the word Ticket) is included in the hyperlink and in the href.  I just want starting from home and ending with 6770).  Please let me know if you have any questions